# Save report of Del Move RD actions from batch to notepad

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to save a report of actions performed

```
del /q /f "C:\Document2Bdeleted*.txt"
del /q /f "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SpecificDocument*.txt"
del /q /f "c:\users\%username%\Downloads\specificInstaller*.exe"
RD /S /Q "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\specificFolder"
RD /S /Q "C:\specificXFolder"
MOVE /y "c:\Users\%username%\Desktop\specificFolderToKeep" c:\SaveFolder
MOVE /Y "C:\specificDocumentToKeep*.txt" C:\SaveFolder
```

I have been trying to use (command below) but I'm not using it correctly

```
dir > a.txt 2>&1
```

I found this command [here](https://superuser.com/questions/793503/cmd-delete-specific-files-and-log-all-output)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how I can make this work? My knowledge in this matter is very basic. The file I am using is a .bat file. Thanks

This is what I found that works for what I needed

This is how to get a list of a file before its deleted

```
dir "Path to file\SpedificDocument*.txt" /s /b >> output.txt
del /q /f "Path to file\SpedificDocument*.txt"
```

You can use RD the same way but only the files will be listed not the directory

```
dir "C:\specificXFolder" /s /b >> output.txt
RD /S /Q "C:\specificXFolder"
```

Move will report that a file was moved with nothing specific if you add `>> output.txt` to the end. (log 1 dir(s) moved.) That is good enough for me

MOVE /Y "C:\specificDocumentToKeep*.txt" C:\SaveFolder >> output.txt

Comment: Are you wanting a report of the actions performed (i.e., the commands that were run), or the results of the commands?  If you are wanting a report of the actions then just use `type %0 >> output.txt` somewhere in the script and it will append all of the commands in the script to output.txt.

Comment: If you are wanting to record the results of the commands, use `>> output.txt` at the end of each line, and it will append the output of the command to output.txt.  If you want a new output.txt file to be created each time, then use `> output.txt` on the first line, and `>> output.txt` on the other lines.

Comment: @Tony I want to record the results of the command. I tried adding >> output.txt but my document is blank after it delets the *.txt for example `del /q /f "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SpecificDocument*.txt" >> output.txt`

Comment: @TonyHinkle When I add a pause in after the del command I see there is no result from the command to record.  It looks like I need to find out how to first search to find the files, output the files found then delete the files

Comment: Yeah--`del` doesn't return any information unless there's an error.  So it sounds like you are wanting to log an entry for each file that is deleted or moved?  If that is the case, I recommend that you edit the question to be very clear about the type of logging you want (provide an example).